# Making SQL statement efficient and easy to understand

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem that I have to make my code shorter .
code:

```
IF @result_var = @expected_value

    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory VALUES
                  (
                              Getdate(),
                              @rule_guid,
                              'Ok',
                              @result_var
                  )
      IF CONVERT(DATE,@check_time) <> CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime())
      BEGIN
        UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules
        SET    ok_days_count =@ok_days_count + 1 ,
                  last_check_time=@check_time
        where  rule_guid=@rule_guid
      END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory VALUES
                  (
                              Getdate(),
                              @rule_guid,
                              'Error',
                              @result_var
                  )
      UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules
      SET    ok_days_count=0,
             last_check_time=@check_time
      WHERE  rule_guid=@rule_guid
    END
```

There have to be only 1 insert and 1 update that is what my boss is saying but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Please edit your answer, highlight only the SQL code and click on the {} button to format as code.  It makes your question easier to read.

Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: And also, try to find out if you're using MySQL or MS SQL Server. (Please remove tag for product not used.)

Comment: I m using sql server 2012

Comment: As your question title talks about "easy to understand", I think you should add the column list to the insert statement.  Inserts with just a value list are inherently harder to maintain, and also more fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF @result_var = @expected_value
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'Ok'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'Error'
END

IF CONVERT(DATE,@check_time) <> CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime())
BEGIN
    SET @ok_days_count = @ok_days_count + 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @ok_days_count = 0;
END


INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory VALUES
(
          Getdate(),
          @rule_guid,
          @Status,
          @result_var
)

UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules
SET    ok_days_count = @ok_days_count ,
          last_check_time=@check_time
where  rule_guid=@rule_guid
```

Comment: THX it seems very easy :)

Comment: Mark the answer as useful if it was.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use case statements within insert and within update. Not that it would make it much easier to understand, but would fulfill your boss' wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (might need a bit of tweaking):

```
INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory 
    VALUES 
    ( 
    Getdate(), 
    @rule_guid, 
    CASE 
        WHEN @result_var = @expected_value 
            then 'Ok'
        ELSE 'Error"
    END, 
    @result_var 
    )
UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules 
SET 
    ok_days_count =@ok_days_count +
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(DATE,@check_time) <> CONVERT(DATE,Sysdatetime())
            then 1
        ELSE
                0
        END,
    last_check_time=@check_time 
    where rule_guid=@rule_guid
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query there is case where you do not have to update columns, i.e. @result_var = @expected_value  and CONVERT(DATE,@check_time) = CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime())

```
DECLARE @Should_Update bit
SET @Should_Update=0

IF @result_var = @expected_value
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'Ok'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'Error'
END



    IF(@result_var = @expected_value)
    BEGIN
        IF CONVERT(DATE,@check_time) <> CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime())
        BEGIN
                SET @Should_Update=1
                SET @ok_days_count = @ok_days_count + 1;

        END     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Should_Update=1
        SET @ok_days_count = 0;
    END



INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory VALUES
(
          Getdate(),
          @rule_guid,
          @Status,
          @result_var
)

UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules
SET    ok_days_count = @ok_days_count ,
          last_check_time=@check_time
where  rule_guid=@rule_guid AND @Should_Update=1
```

Comment: problem is that if I run this procedure more than one time a day becouse this script is a part of procedure , i want that my ok_days_count grow if there have not been errors but now it is only changing from 0 to 1

Comment: @NilsOzols can you plsease give some more details so that we can understand your this problem more clearly..

Comment: Ok , problem is that this procedure checks for errors every hour if error has found in script it changes ok_days_count to 0 else it rises it by 1 but it rises ok_day_count only once a day . In the case when there is no errors and the ok_day_count is already rised by one today it stays the same.

Comment: Then in this case you need to maintain one column in the table may be date type having name 'LastUpdatedDate'
Then in update statement we will check whether that entry has already been updated on that date or not.If it is already updated then do not increase the count else increase the count by 1.

Comment: how can i insert script here , first time asking for help in this site.

Comment: once you enter into into comments section you will get one help panel below to the text box with light yellow color background, you can use that to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
     IF @result_var = @expected_value
BEGIN
  SET @Status = 'Ok'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @Status = 'Error'
END
IF @Status = 'Ok'
BEGIN
  IF CONVERT(DATE, @check_time) <> CONVERT(DATE, Sysdatetime())
  BEGIN
    SET @ok_days_count = @ok_days_count + 1;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    @ok_days_count=@ok_days_count
  END
end
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @ok_days_count = 0;
end
INSERT INTO reports.consistencycheckhistory VALUES
            (
                        Getdate(),
                        @rule_guid,
                        @Status,
                        @result_var
            )
UPDATE reports.consistencycheckrules
SET    ok_days_count = @ok_days_count,
       last_check_time = @check_time
WHERE  rule_guid = @rule_guid
```

This seems like the right answer